# Do I need a visa to enter UK just to rehearse with my band?

Tags: visas, uk

Returned home after studying in the UK where I am in a band.  While waiting for visa approval to return to the UK as a working musician, can I enter the UK on a visit visa to rehearse with the band?

Comment: Is anybody paying you for this rehearsal time?

Comment: No, we don't get paid..

Comment: Thanks DJClayworth.  Is rehearsing considered as work?  as with a standard visitor visa, one can not do paid or unpaid work. Is staying 10 days in a month means living in the UK for long periods of time through frequent visits?

Answer (score 4):

The UK visa policy is that only one type of permission can be valid at any given time. You were in the UK as a student, and departed. You then applied for a visa that would allow you to be in the UK to work as a musician.

Making a second, separate application to visit is risky, as you've already informed the authorities that you would like to return there to work. You might invite a refusal on one, or both, applications. Perhaps it would be wiser to await the decision on the more important visa, the one that would let you perform with your band.